# Triggering InvalidModelStateResponseFactory when ModelState is invalid

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I am writing an API using asp.net core 3.0 and have configured my application with the following behavior for all controllers:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers()
        .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(setupAction =>
        {
            setupAction.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
            {
                var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails(context.ModelState)
                {
                    Type = "https://courselibrary.com/modelvalidationproblem",
                    Title = "One or more model validation errors occurred.",
                    Status = StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity,
                    Detail = "See the errors property for details",
                    Instance = context.HttpContext.Request.Path
                };

                problemDetails.Extensions.Add("traceId", context.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier);

                return new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(problemDetails)
                {
                    ContentTypes = { "application/problem+json" }
                };
            };
        });
    ...
}
```

This works great with data annotations on my input (ex: `[Required]`) class's properties. It returns a 422 Unprocessable Entity reponse like this if any annotations fail:

```
{
    "type": "https://courselibrary.com/modelvalidationproblem",
    "title": "One or more model validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 422,
    "detail": "See the errors property for details",
    "instance": "/api/songbooks/21924d66-dac6-43a5-beee-206de4d35216/songs",
    "traceId": "0HLQFGSFIFL5L:00000001",
    "errors": {
        "Title": [
            "The Title field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

However, I am implementing FluentValudation in my controller like this:

```
if (!newSong.IsValid)
{
    newSong.Validate().AddToModelState(ModelState, null);
    _logger.LogWarning("{method} failed model validation (ModelState: {@modelState}), returning Unprocessable Entity", nameof(Post), ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors));
    return UnprocessableEntity(ModelState);                
}
```

However, this doesn't trigger the `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` like the built-in validation does.

Does anyone know how I can trigger the same sort of event from within my controller to use this convenient handler?

Comment: You won't be able to "trigger" it per se, your controller's action method will have to return `UnprocessableEntityObjectResult`.

Comment: Yeah, I was concerned about that. I ended up creating a static class that basically encapsulates the behavior in `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory` and simply use it in both places (the controller and `Startup.cs`). Thankfully I have ModelState and HttpContext in both places... I'll post what I ended up with if no one else has any suggestions.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, there is a pretty simple answer. Rather than returning an `ActionResult` of `Ok()` or `BadRequest()` or whatnot, by using this ValidationProblem pattern, you can simply return `ValidationProblem(ModelState)` and it'll use the factory set up in the `Startup.cs` Api configuration!

So here's what I can do instead:

```
if (!newSong.IsValid)
{
    newSong.Validate().AddToModelState(ModelState, null);
    _logger.LogWarning("{method} failed model validation (ModelState: {@modelState}), returning Unprocessable Entity", nameof(Post), ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors));
    return ValidationProblem(ModelState);                
}
```

In addition, you'll need to override the behavior to pull it out from your startup like this (Thanks to Kevin Dockx for this idea):

```
public override ActionResult ValidationProblem([ActionResultObjectValue] ModelStateDictionary modelStateDictionary)
    {
        var options = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions>>();
        return (ActionResult)options.Value.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory(ControllerContext);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please add a full example of what to do with overrider of ValidationProblem ?

Comment: @ArtemA create class `BaseController`, create `ValidationProblem` override method and inherit your controller with it. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/64517172/2925210 for custom implementation of `InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`.