# How I can adjust which fields I will have in the response of a model validation (.NET Core Web Api)?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have the following response:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "name": [
      "The Name field is required."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|df89b6cf-4d6da62fe5671a5c."
}
```

Actually, I don't need `type`, `title` and `traceId`.

I don't have any additional configuration in the `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MainConnectionString")));
    
    services.AddAuthenticationWithBearer(Configuration);

    services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
        {
            NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy
            {
                ProcessDictionaryKeys = true,
                OverrideSpecifiedNames = true,
                ProcessExtensionDataNames = true
            },
        };
    });
        
    services.AddSwaggerConfiguration();
}
```

And I have very simple model:

```
public class UpdateProfileRequest
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string About { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string JobInfo { get; set; }
    public string HobbyInfo { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is the action of the controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("[action]")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
public IActionResult UpdateProfile(UpdateProfileRequest request)
{
    
    return Ok(new {UserName = "test"});
}
```

So, the question. How to remove for each response the fields: `type`, `title` and `traceId`.
Is there so simple way?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I have solved it with the most elegant way as I can. To do that I have been forced to make a little research in the framework's inner mechanisms.

1. I created the following method in a static class with method like:

```
        public static IActionResult MakeValidationResponse(ActionContext context)
        {
            var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails(context.ModelState)
            {
                Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
            };
            // My app calls Chat, so, that's why I called this var as chatProblemDetails
            var chatProblemDetails = new ChatProblemDetails
            {
                Status = problemDetails.Status,
                Errors = problemDetails.Errors,
            };
            
            var result = new BadRequestObjectResult(chatProblemDetails);

            result.ContentTypes.Add("application/problem+json");

            return result;
        }
    }
```

2. Created DTO class for the response:

```
    public class ChatProblemDetails
    {
        public int? Status { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, string[]> Errors { get; set; }
    }
```

3. Finally, added the following configuration on the `Startup.cs` class:

```
services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = InvalidModelStateResponse.MakeValidationResponse;
    }). ...
```

And profit! Now validation response looks like:

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "errors": {
    "name": [
      "The Name field is required."
    ]
  }
}
```

No `traceId`, no `type`, no redundant noise! Thank you for reading!

Comment: Content-type `application/problem+json` means [RFC 7807](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7807). If you do not want to use RFC 7807 - you should use default content type.