# Why do I have to override ValidationProblem to use InvalidModelStateResponseFactory in api action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Based on a video by Kevin Dockx, I'm trying to configure my api to return `422 UnprocessableEntity` instead of `400 BadRequest` on validation errors. (See code below)

The configuration works for validation errors that are handled by the default binding/validation.  However, if I try to return any custom validation problems from within the action (i.e. `return ValidationProblem(ModelState)`), the custom response factory does not appear to be used.

I found [this thread on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58360182/triggering-invalidmodelstateresponsefactory-when-modelstate-is-invalid) that shows how to override ValidationProblem() on the controller.  This works -- but I'm curious why it is necessary.  I guess I assumed that configuring the API behavior in Program.cs was kind of a global thing -- that all validation problems would be handled by my configured factory.

**Is there a way to have the framework use the configured InvalidModelStateResponseFactory for all validation issues without having to override controller methods?**

**Program.cs**

```cs
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
    {
        //Return validation errors as 422 instead of 400
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context => {
            var factory = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ProblemDetailsFactory>();

            var problemDetails = factory.CreateValidationProblemDetails(context.HttpContext, context.ModelState);

            problemDetails.Detail = "See the errors field for details.";
            problemDetails.Instance = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

            problemDetails.Status = StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity;
            problemDetails.Title = "One or more validation errors occurred.";
            problemDetails.Type = "https://example.com/api/modelvalidationproblem";

            return new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(problemDetails)
            {
                ContentTypes = { "application/problem+json" }
            };
        };
    });
```

Comment: You can create a validation filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#automatic-http-400-responses) here:

> The [ApiController] attribute makes model validation errors
> automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response. Consequently, the
> following code is unnecessary in an action method:
>
> if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
> return BadRequest(ModelState); }
>
> It uses the ModelStateInvalidFilter action filter to do the preceding
> check.

You could check the description here:

[image]

It's just for the atuomatic response with `ApiController` attribute

If you don't want to override the target method in each controller,just create a filter：

```
public class BadRequestFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (context.Result is BadRequestResult or BadRequestObjectResult)
            {
                var options = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions>>();
                var result = (ActionResult)options.Value.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory(context);
                context.Result = result;

            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
                 
        }
    }
```

apply it to all controllers:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(op=>op.Filters.Add<BadRequestFilter>())
```

in controller:

```
if(!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return BadRequest();
}
```